# Angular 2 hide/show template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

is there a possiblitity to hide and show div with specific person query?
I know that there is a ngIf and hidden, but both of them uses boolean.

I want something lik that

```js
User.Admin = 'admin',
User.Worker = 'worker',
User.HelpDesk ='helpDesk'
```

```html
<div ngIf="User.Admin">
  show content
</div>
```

Is this somehow possible?

thx in advance

Comment: Yes it is -> *ngIf="User.Admin === 'admin' "

Comment: Whats wrong with NgIf and boolean? I dont follow.
There's nothing stopping you writing a small function to validate the user however you want and returning true/false

Comment: actually i dont´t want show the real login User in html

Answer (score 3):

If you just have one html element you want to show or not, you can easily do this with `*ngIf`:

```html
<div *ngIf="User.Admin === 'admin'">
  show content
</div>
```

If you have like a roles variable instead of the 3 flags you could do something like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="User.Role">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'admin'">
        <!-- content for admin -->
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'worker'">
        <!-- content for worker -->
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'helpdesk'">
        <!-- content for helpdesk -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. Maye this is the best way. But instead of 'admin' I will use a variable (ng-model),

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use *ngIf  due to performance, you can alternativly use:

```
`[style.visibility]`
```

like: 
`<div [style.visibility]=" (User.Admin === 'admin') ? 'hidden' : 'visible'> <!-- content --> </div>"`